# Jsp not setting session variable after form submission

Tags: java, forms, jsp, session, authentication

I have a simple login form, in jsp, that when clicked checks the user and logs them in by setting a session variable called `loggedIn`.

It appears to set the session variable after I initially submit the login form because it displays the "You are logged in." text. But if I reload the page after submitting the login form with correct login details it displays the login form again!

Am I doing the correct check on the `loggedIn` session?

Here is the servlet code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="com.servlet.explore.*, java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
<%
boolean isValid = false;
if(request.getParameter("loginSubmit") != null){
    String username = request.getParameter("username").trim();
    String password = request.getParameter("password").trim();

    // insert hashed password and username
    LoginController cc = new LoginController();
    password = cc.hashPassword(password);
    // check details are valid
    isValid = cc.checkUser(username, password);

    // if login details are valid set the session variable loggedIn to true
    if(isValid){
        session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "true");
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML page:

```
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

        <%
            // is the user logged in?
            if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn") != null){
                out.println("You are logged in.");
            }else{
                out.println("<form class=\"boxShadow\" id=\"loginForm\" name=\"loginForm\" action=\"admin.jsp\" method=\"POST\">"+
                        "<p>You must login to view this page</p>"+
                        "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" placeholder=\"username\" required>"+
                        "<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"username\" required>"+
                        "<input type=\"text\" name=\"botCatcher\" class=\"botCatcher\" placeholder=\"username\">"+
                        "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"loginSubmit\" value=\"submit\" id=\"loginSubmit\">"+
                        "</form>");
            }
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

This problem doesn't occur when I run the jsp through eclipse using a local Tomcat server. Only when I publish the application on my remote Tomcat server.

Edit: added some logs
catalina.out

> Jul 03, 2014 4:01:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployWAR INFO: Deploying web application archive
>   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/chrismepham.war Jul 03, 2014
>   4:15:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearReferencesJdbc SEVERE: The web application [/chrismepham]
>   registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to
>   unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a
>   memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. Jul 03,
>   2014 4:15:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/chrismepham]
>   appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup
>   thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Jul 03, 2014 4:15:33 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources INFO:
>   Undeploying context [/chrismepham] Jul 03, 2014 4:16:36 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web
>   application archive
>   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/chrismepham.war Jul 03, 2014
>   4:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearReferencesJdbc SEVERE: The web application [/chrismepham]
>   registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to
>   unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a
>   memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. Jul 03,
>   2014 4:28:11 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/chrismepham]
>   appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup
>   thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Jul 03, 2014 4:28:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources INFO:
>   Undeploying context [/chrismepham] Jul 03, 2014 4:28:50 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web
>   application archive
>   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/chrismepham.war

Comment: is your browser cookie enabled?

Comment: The log from the remote Tomcat server would be useful, could you add it to the issue?

Comment: I added catalina.out log. I also create a test web app and it seems to set the session variable fine. Is there some setting or something I might have set in eclipse that would stop sessions on this app?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check (you can try adding logs.. lots of logs)

1. Is the browser caching the HTML output and showing the same thing again? (Server log will not have new lines when you click on browser reload)
2. JSP is compiled to a servlet on deployment.. so if redeployment is not proper, the old servlet could be running. Try restarting remote tomcat or using the admin console to stop and start the application.

ATB..

Comment: I now have 2 webapps running, 1 works fine, the other doesnt?